# SI To DI copy error for reverse

Tags: assembly

Suppose We have number 321 which **si** points to offset **1**
and temp's offset is in **di** .

```
mov di,offset temp
```

Now we want to copy from si to di by this commands :

```
mov cx,3
reverse:
 mov dl,byte ptr [si]
 mov byte ptr[di],dl
 inc di
 dec si
loop reverse
mov byte ptr[di],'$'
```

but outputs me 113 not 123 , it means the integer 2 will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the initial conditions really are as you describe, I think your `temp` storage area must overlap with the original input: I don't see how your loop would result in a duplicate "1" otherwise.

Specifically, I would guess that `temp` points to the byte immediately after the beginning of the original input (as a really wild guess: perhaps the buffer where "321" is reserved in a data section, and has been accidentally declared as only a single byte, and `temp` is declared immediately afterwards).

i.e. initially:

```
   buffer for original number
     |
     |  temp (== di) actually points here
     |   |
     v   v
---+---+---+---+---+---
   | 3 | 2 | 1 |   |   
---+---+---+---+---+---
             ^
             |
        initial si
```

After the first iteration, the "1" has overwritten the "2":

```
        temp
         |
         v  di
---+---+---+---+---+---
   | 3 | 1 | 1 |   |   
---+---+---+---+---+---
        si
```

After the second iteration, the "1" (which was originally a "2") is copied over the original "1":

```
        temp
         |
         v      di
---+---+---+---+---+---
   | 3 | 1 | 1 |   |   
---+---+---+---+---+---
    si
```

After the third iteration, the "3" is copied:

```
        temp
         |
         v          di
---+---+---+---+---+---
   | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 |   
---+---+---+---+---+---
si
```

...and finally with the `$` on the end:

```
        temp
         |
         v          di
---+---+---+---+---+---
   | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | $ 
---+---+---+---+---+---
si
```

...so `temp` now points to "113".

Comment: Yes , you are right . I have changed the  temp's offset in data segment and every thing turn on its best .

Answer (score 2):

Looks okay to me - step through it in a debugger to see where it goes awry.

Comment: The other answer is more spoon-feeding, but asm programmers should know how to use a debugger to find their own mistakes. So, +1 :)